# How can I acquire JanusGraphManagement over a remote connection?

Tags: java, gremlin, janusgraph, gremlin-server

I have a docker container running the gremlin-server.

It was started via:

```
./bin/gremlin-server.sh conf/gremlin-server/gremlin-server.yaml
```

From within a docker container, running this image:
https://hub.docker.com/r/janusgraph/janusgraph

The server is up and is listening at port 8182

```
$ docker ps
6019adda6081        janusgraph/janusgraph                                         "docker-entrypoint.s…"   2 days ago          Up 26 hours         0.0.0.0:8182->8182/tcp
```

I am interested in using a schema and indexes.

Janus offers this here: https://docs.janusgraph.org/basics/schema/

The following Is the configuration I use to attempt to connect to the gremlin-server:

```
AbstractConfiguration config = new BaseConfiguration();

    config.setListDelimiter('/');
    // contents of conf/remote-graph.properties
    config.setProperty("gremlin.remote.driver.sourceName", "g");
    config.setProperty("gremlin.remote.remoteConnectionClass", "org.apache.tinkerpop.gremlin.driver.remote.DriverRemoteConnection");
    // contents of conf/remote-objects.yaml:
    config.setProperty("clusterConfiguration.hosts", databaseUrl);
    config.setProperty("clusterConfiguration.port", 8182);
    config.setProperty("clusterConfiguration.serializer.className", "org.apache.tinkerpop.gremlin.driver.ser.GryoMessageSerializerV3d0/");

    config.setProperty("storage.backend", "cql");
    config.setProperty("clusterConfiguration.serializer.config.ioRegistries", "org.janusgraph.graphdb.tinkerpop.JanusGraphIoRegistry");
```

When I call

```
GraphTraversalSource g = traversal().withRemote(config);
```

I get a traversal source and everything seems fine. However, to use the management stuff that Janus provides, I seem to need a `JanusGraphManagement` object. I cannot get the generic `Graph` object above and cast it to a `JanusGraph`. The docs suggest using a JanusGraphFactory: https://docs.janusgraph.org/basics/configuration/#janusgraphfactory

So I call

```
    JanusGraph janusGraph = JanusGraphFactory.open(config);
```

I get the following stack trace:

```java
    Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Could not find implementation class: org.janusgraph.diskstorage.cql.CQLStoreManager
    at org.janusgraph.util.system.ConfigurationUtil.instantiate(ConfigurationUtil.java:60)
    at org.janusgraph.diskstorage.Backend.getImplementationClass(Backend.java:440)
    at org.janusgraph.diskstorage.Backend.getStorageManager(Backend.java:411)
    at org.janusgraph.graphdb.configuration.builder.GraphDatabaseConfigurationBuilder.build(GraphDatabaseConfigurationBuilder.java:50)
    at org.janusgraph.core.JanusGraphFactory.open(JanusGraphFactory.java:161)
    at org.janusgraph.core.JanusGraphFactory.open(JanusGraphFactory.java:132)
    at org.janusgraph.core.JanusGraphFactory.open(JanusGraphFactory.java:112)
    at com.activitystream.database.GraphMigration.migrateDatabase(GraphMigration.java:69)
    at com.activitystream.runners.persistence.DataStores.migrateDatabase(DataStores.java:27)
    at com.activitystream.runners.persistence.EntityPersistenceRunner.main(EntityPersistenceRunner.java:23)
    Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.janusgraph.diskstorage.cql.CQLStoreManager
    at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.BuiltinClassLoader.loadClass(BuiltinClassLoader.java:581)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.ClassLoaders$AppClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoaders.java:178)
    at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:522)
    at java.base/java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
at java.base/java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:315)
at org.janusgraph.util.system.ConfigurationUtil.instantiate(ConfigurationUtil.java:56)
    ... 9 more
```

Is it possible to modify the schema over a remote connection?

If it is not possible, how can one modify the schema?

Any insight would be appreciated.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You basically have two choices - either:

1. Interact with your `JanusGraphManagement` object by [way of scripts](https://tinkerpop.apache.org/docs/current/reference/#gremlin-java-scripts) sent to Gremlin Server (typically by way of a session but I guess you could package an entire "management script" together and submit it as one request) or
2. Bypass Gremlin Server and instantiation your `JanusGraphManagement` object locally as directed in the JanusGraph documentation.

There is no way to have return a `JanusGraphManagement` to your client as it is not a serializable object that can be sent back from the server.

Comment: Thank you for clearing this up. 

I am currently trying out step #2. 
I have the following lines in my "empty-sample.groovy"
`
PropertyKey streamIdKey;
if(!mgmt.containsPropertyKey("stream_id")) {
    streamIdKey = mgmt.makePropertyKey("stream_id").dataType(String.class).cardinality(Cardinality.SINGLE).make();
`
But the groovy script complains that it does not recognize the `Cardinality` class.
(which is a part of `org.janusgraph.core`).

How can one add classes to the execution context of the startupscript?

Comment: adding `import org.janusgraph.core.Cardinality` at the top of your script should resolve that.

Comment: What worked for me was referencing the Cardinality class by full package name. 
E.g. `.cardinality(org.janusgraph.core.Cardinality.SINGLE).make())`
As per suggestion here -> https://github.com/JanusGraph/janusgraph/issues/1262

Comment: @stephenmallette I'm facing the exact same issue and want to avoid approach 2.
Can you elaborate on the first option or maybe provide a link to a sample snippet.

Comment: anything you would do with approach 2, you can just send as a script from a driver. i see the link i had in the answer is broken...i've updated it.